# If number in range was >= 100 and subsequently <100

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Anyone got any ideas on how to do this?

[image]

I'm trying to build a spreadsheet that helps me monitor the performance of my blog articles. So if the article historically had >=100 visits at any point but **subsequently** gets <100 at any point I want to know about it.

The formula I've been playing with is:

```
=IF(((FILTER(C2:G2,C2:G2<>E2))>=100 AND (FILTER(C2:G2,C2:G2<>E2))<100, "Article Failing", ""))
```

I'm using Filter btw because I need to exclude column E, which is the delta between this month's & last month's numbers.

I know the formula isn't logically right but struggling to think of a way to do it.

**Edit:**
Here's a link to the spreadsheet with desired output https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TeaQ6oUbJDeKxUi8tvvCWXtw0oK9d5IVO60j1UbQCK8/edit?usp=sharing

Here's a table showing the sample data and desired output:

| Total users (last 30 days) | Total users (prev 30 days) | Delta - Total users | Total users last 30-60 days | Total users prev 60-90 days | Delta - Total users | Above 100 | Article Failing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 651 | 90 | -417 | 772 | 249 | 523 | Tweak Article | Failing |
| 610 | 570 | 40 | 550 | 432 | 118 | Tweak Article | OK |
| 436 | 409 | 27 | 328 | 210 | 118 | Tweak Article | OK |
| 422 | 288 | 134 | 53 | 288 | -235 | Tweak Article | OK |
| 95 | 476 | -90 | 417 | 477 | -60 | Below100 | Failing |
| 337 | 179 | 158 | 129 | 182 | -53 | Tweak Article | OK |
| 305 | 395 | -90 | 318 | 343 | -25 | Tweak Article | OK |
| 304 | 348 | -44 | 299 | 253 | 46 | Tweak Article | OK |
| 302 | 277 | 25 | 283 | 317 | -34 | Tweak Article | OK |
| 286 | 252 | 34 | 268 | 281 | -13 | Tweak Article | OK |
| 213 | 193 | 20 | 221 | 168 | 53 | Tweak Article | OK |
| 157 | 138 | 19 | 132 | 166 | -34 | Tweak Article | OK |
| 150 | 157 | -7 | 110 | 68 | 42 | Tweak Article | OK |

I've made cells B2 & A6 be failing articles i.e. they were >=100 but have since gone below 100. The end column 'Article Failing' is where I'm trying to create the formula.

Hope that makes things a bit clearer.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: In order to track historical performance, you need a **log** of those historical visit numbers, or at the minimum a place to store the highest-ever value. Please edit the question to show what you have.

Comment: Hi both - sorry about that, I've edited the original question to give more info.

Comment: @doubleunary, yep I have that data in the spreadsheet already (example now attached) in the real version it gets pulled in automatically every month, so there will always be 4 months' worth of up-to-date comparative data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This formula will match the desired results you show in the sample spreadsheet:

```
=if( 
  (max(A$2:A2) >= 100) * (A2 < 100) 
  + 
  (max(B$2:B2) >= 100) * (B2 < 100) 
  + 
  (row(B2) = row(B$2)) * (B2 < 100), 
  "Failing", 
  "OK" 
)
```

Comment: @JonWright, you can use this formula to create a named function that you may reuse in the future. see [Create & use named functions](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12504534?hl=en)